# Retrieve Parameters.scriptPath on python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-devops, pipeline

I'm currently using a custom python script to compile my application, and I would like to access the "Parameters.scriptPath" parameter while running my script. I've constructed the script to run in multiple versions of python, and now I would like to use the same interpreter to run subprocesses during compilation time (like database migration scripts).

Is there a way I can access this variable?

I've already checked the environment variables and this parameter is not there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Would it be possible to give some code examples, or further elaborate on what you have tried (with examples). This should help someone have a better chance to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Python script can not access the **scriptPath** which is the parameter of the task. Did you know [Use Python Version task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python?view=azure-devops#use-a-specific-python-version) ? If you add this task in your pipeline, you can access the varaible **python.version**.

In another way, the Agent variable `Agent.ToolsDirectory` can be used by Use Python Version task to switch between multiple versions of a tool. These tasks will add tools from this directory to PATH so that subsequent build steps can use them.